# Identify the files year wise and delete from a dir in unix

Tags: shell, unix, unix-timestamp

I need to list out the files which are created in a specific year and then to delete the files. year should be the input.

i tried with date it is working for me. but not able to covert that date to year for comparison in loop to get the list of files.

Below code is giving 05/07 files. but want to list out the files which are created in 2022,2021,etc.,

```
    for file in /tmp/abc*txt ; do
    [ "$(date -I -r "$file")" == "2022-05-07" ] && ls -lstr "$file"
done
```

Comment: `date -r`  produces the file modification time, but in the question's text, you talk about file creation time. Please clarify.

Comment: Also, since you tagged your question with _shell_ (i.e. Posix shell): POSIX requires the comparision done by `=`, not `==`. See [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you end up doing `ls -l`  anyway, you might just parse the date information from the output. (However, generally [don't use `ls` in scripts.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs))

```
ls -ltr | awk '$8 ~ /^202[01]$/'
```

`date -r` is not portable, though if you have it, you could do

```
for file in /tmp/abc*txt ; do
    case $(date -I -r "$file") in
        2020-* | 2021-* ) ls -l "$file";;
    esac
done
```

(The `-t` and `-r` flags to `ls` have no meaning when you are listing a single file anyway.)

If you don't, the tool of choice would be `stat`, but it too has portability issues; the precise options to get the information you want will vary between platforms. On Linux, try

```
for file in /tmp/abc*txt ; do
    case $(LC_ALL=C stat -c %y "$file") in
        2020-* | 2021-* ) ls -l "$file";;
    esac
done
```

On BSD (including MacOS) try `stat -f %Sm -t %Y "$file"` to get just the year.

If you need proper portability, perhaps look for a scripting language with wide support, such as Perl or Python. The `stat()` system call is the fundamental resource for getting metainformation about a file. The `find` command also has some features for finding files by age, though its default behavior is to traverse subdirectories, too (you can inhibit that with `-maxdepth 1`; but then the options to select files by age are again not entirely POSIX portable).

Comment: It worked thanks!. So instead of listing files can i delete it in same way ? by using below ? case $(LC_ALL=C stat -c %y "$file") in
        2020-* | 2021-* ) rm "$file";;
    esac

Comment: Sure, absolutely (though probably run it with `ls` first to see which files it will pick out).

Comment: For what it's worth, the `LC_ALL=C` is to ensure that the date format is not some weird localized version with the year in an unpredictable place.

Comment: I ran it with ls. it gives quickly. but when i ran with rm, it's keep on running no output is displaying.

Comment: I find that hard to believe. Are there additional details which you are not sharing? Maybe try to run it with `bash -x` for debugging.

Comment: (Nothing here is Bash-specific per se, so `sh -x` should also work.)

Answer (score 0):

To list out  files which were *last modified* in a specific year and then to delete those files, you could use a combination of the `find -newer` and `touch` commands:

```sh
# given a year as input
year=2022
stampdir=$(mktemp -d)
touch -t ${year}01010000 "$stampdir"/beginning
touch -t $((year+1))01010000 "$stampdir"/end
find /tmp -name 'abc*txt' -type f -newer "$stampdir/beginning" ! -newer "$stampdir/end" -print -delete
rm -r "$stampdir"
```

First, create a temporary working directory to store the timestamp files; we don't want the `find` command to accidentally find them. Be careful here; `mktemp` will probably create a directory in /tmp; this use-case is safe only because we're naming the timestamp files such that they don't match the "abc*txt" pattern from the question.

Next, create bordering timestamp files with the `touch` command: one that is the newest date in the year, named "beginning", and another for the newest date of the next year, named "end".

Then run the `find` command; here's the breakdown:

- start in /tmp (from the question)
- files named with the 'abc*txt' pattern (from the question)
- only files (not directories, etc -- from the question)
- newer than the beginning timestamp file
- not newer (i.e. older) than the end timestamp file
- if found, print the filename and then delete it

Finally, clean up the temporary working directory that we created.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

For checking which files are picked up:

echo -e "Give Year :"

read yr

ls -ltr /tmp | grep "^-" |grep -v ":" | grep $yr | awk -F " " '{ print $9;}'

** You can replace { print $9 ;} with { rm  $9; } in the above command for deleting the picked files

Comment: No, `rm` is not an Awk command. See also [useless use of `grep`.](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: Also, this will fetch any files which contain the year e.g. in the file name or owner information.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).